# What mode should I be in for different tasks?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-ce

The most common tasks I perform after deploying my webshop to production mode are css updates/changes, product updates/changes, and small admin panel changes (i.e. catalog/cart price rules, page mods through the admin panel).

Of course, the manual states the necessary actions needed after each change, i.e. Reindexing after a catalog change, or content deployment after a css change.

But I've never seen anything stating whether I should be in production mode, or developer mode.  Which mode is necessary for which type if task, because changing permissions each time, clearing directories each time, re compiling and re deploying each time are a headache.

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete guide about the moods.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html

Comment: I saw that as I was going through the manual, as I'm sure many people have. Unfortunately no examples are provided as to tasks,  its merely an explanation of each mode.  Although its a nice explanation, without examples, do I assume that every task I  previously stated requires developer mode because files are being edited in some way?

Comment: in that case `developer mode` work for you.